# undefined al seleccionar el valor del atributo id de un button html luego agregar este button por medio de ajax jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Sucede que cargo unos botones por medio del método append de jquery, esto en el success de una llamada ajax al servidor para obtener unos valores que pondré en el id cada boton así como en su value. Cuando la página me carga, esta muestra todos los botones pero cuando intento ingresar al atributo por medio de `$('#id-valor').attr('value');` y/o `$('#id-valor').val()` me muestra undefined a que se debe?

El código de mi javascript es el siguiente:

```
$('select#estado option:selected').each(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/mis-solicitudes/filtrar-estado',
                data: {id_usuario: $('#id_oculto').val(), estado: $(this).html()},
                type: 'GET',
                //dataType:'json',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.length>0){
                        for(var i = 0; i<response.length; i++){
                        $('#cuerpo-tabla').append("<tr id='tr-"+i+"'>"+"<th>"+parseInt(i)+parseInt(1)+"</th>"+"<td>"+response[i][1]+"</td>"+
                            "<td><button type='button' id='btn-editar"+parseInt(i+1)+"' value='"+response[i][0]+"' class='btn btn-outline-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' data-whatever='@mdo'>Editar</button></td>"+
                            "<th scope='row'><button id='btn-pausar' type=button' class='btn btn-outline-warning'>Pausar</button></th>"+
                      "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger'>Anular</button></td>"+
                      "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-info'>Visualizar</button></td>"+
                      "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-dark'>Archivar</button></td></tr>");
                        }   
                    }
                    else{
                        $('tbody tr').remove();
                    }

                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    console.log('Disculpe, ocurrió un problema '+ error)
                },
                complete: function(xhr, status){
                    console.log('Petición realizada')
                }
            }); 
        });
    }).change();
```

Quiero agregar que cada vez que pongo inspeccionar en el browser en la seccion donde se agregan esos botones, puedo visualizarlos. Pero cuando pongo ver código fuente no aparacen.

Comment: Saludos Luis, bienvenido a SOEs, mayúsculas equivale a gritar, edita el título por favor.

Comment: Te refieres al botón **btn-editar#**? Cómo intentas acceder a sus propiedades? Por cierto, si ves el código fuente en el navegador, aparece solo lo generado antes de cualquier acción Javascript y debes hacer clic derecho sobre un elemento y seleccionar la opción **Inspeccionar** para analizar cómo fue creado.

Comment: @Triby sí exacto, es el btn-editar# del que quiero sacar el atributo value y lo hago por medio de jquery con las funciones attr() y/o val()  y la asigno a un console.log(funcion()) como esta arriba. Ya inspeccione con Inspeccionar y aparece, pero cuando pongo ver codigo fuente no aparece nada.

Comment: Primero : En ver código fuente no se va a ver ya que eso se construye después con la petición ajax. Te recomiendo inspeccionar y vas a la pestaña Sources desde allí puedes depurar paso a paso el codigo.

Segundo : Como estas accediendo al botón? muestra por favor

Comment: @HectorLara El boton si se displaya cuando carga la página, en realidad son varios botones, ya que cuando carga la pagina se encuentra con un evento que selecciona el option seleccionado por defecto, es ahi donde construye...a que te refieres cuando dices accediendo? yo solo quiero obtener el value del boton cargado por ajax  y lo hago mediante dos funciones jquery attr() y/o val().

Comment: @Luis De La Peña es que solo veo la parte de los select pero no veo la parte donde intentas obtener el valor  con .val o attr("value")

Comment: @HectorLara imprimo en consola inmediatamente después de terminada la instrucción .change();. Imprimo con console.log($('#btn-editar-1').val());

Comment: Este código va a generar un problema de elementos con IDs duplicados.

Comment: Creo que te sobra un guión al hacer el console.log("#btn-editar**-**1").val(), porque no existe cuando creas el botón: id='btn-editar"+parseInt(i+1)+"', realmente queda como btn-editar1

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en realidad cada boton queda con un ID diferente ya que la variable i va aumentando por cada itercion for

Comment: @Triby tienes razon pero solo es porque lo redacte mal

Comment: @HectorLara tienes razon ya entendí que no se puede acceder al id de un button creado por ajax fuera de la funcion success, ya que ahi es donde ya existe. Solo tenía que colocar  attr() y/o val() dentro del success y ya no aparece undefined si no su valor real. Gracias, se pudo arreglar todo.